# XML editor wanted - showing XML information as forms, lists etc., user needs no XML knowledge

Tags: software-rec, xml

I am looking for an XML editor, that can be configured for a specific XML format, so that the end user doesn't have to know what XML is, but can just edit the files as if they were forms. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a WYSIWYG XML editor.  There are many. [ArborText](http://www.ptc.com/products/arbortext/) [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor.html#WYSIWYG_XML_Editor)
 [Authentic](http://www.altova.com/authentic/wysiwyg-xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC any browser can display XML in any way you want, you just have to write an xslt style sheet to tell the browser just how it should display it.

edit: [xslt tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)